# someone help me on this react native problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-component

So here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { Profile } from './HomePageComponents/Profile';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

function Main() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Main</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name='Main' component={Main} />
            <Tab.Screen name='Profile' component={<Profile />} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}



export { Home }
```

and here is my Profile.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'

export function Profile() {
  return (
    <View>
        <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
})
```

my problem is that when i tried to render Home.js, i got an error saying "Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'Profile'. It must be a valid React Component" and i just can't figure out whats wrong with my code.. i would appreciate if someone could help me on this.

Comment: I suggest editing your question to have a succinct, meaningful title (asking for help... doesn't help).

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem".

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the component

```
<Tab.Screen name='Profile' component={<Profile />} />
```

Just remove the </>

```
<Tab.Screen name='Profile' component={Profile} />
```